# Highcharts datetime axis labels according to data point groups

Tags: datetime, highcharts, axis-labels

Is it possible to have labels on datetime xAxis that correspond to dataGrouping?
For example I have `dataGrouping` such that data are grouped into days / weeks / months / year:

```
dataGrouping : {
  groupPixelWidth: 250,
  units : [
    ['day', [1]], ['week', [1]], ['month', [1]], ['year', [1]]
  ]
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/CHR7F/2/

There is plenty of options in the highcharts api, but no one seems to achieve the same result as dataGrouping.

The most promising was:

```
xAxis: {
   labels: {
       step: 1
   }
}
```

but still there are two weeks between ticks while data is grouped by months.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution with `tickPositioner`. It is still a workaround, but at least it works.

```
xAxis: {
  tickPositioner: function(){
    ticks = this.series[0].processedXData;
    ticks.info = this.series[0].currentDataGrouping;
    return ticks;
  }
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/CHR7F/3/

Answer (score 0):

On thesame level as setting `units` you cna set `datetimeLebelFormats`, see: http://api.highcharts.com/highstock#plotOptions.area.dataGrouping.dateTimeLabelFormats

Comment: That only affect what is displayed in the tooltip. The axis labels are not affected.

Comment: Right, sorry! In xAxis, you have also accessto the same options: http://api.highcharts.com/highstock#xAxis.dateTimeLabelFormats

Comment: But still, with that I can only change the format of the labels. But the problem is, that when current grouping is 1 month, the ticks shouldn't have 2 weeks interval (http://jsfiddle.net/CHR7F/2/)